# Stop truncation of shortcodes in custom text fields?

Tags: custom-field, shortcode

I have a custom theme that a third party developed for me and I’m trying to get to the bottom of a problem with shortcodes. I’m fairly new to Wordpress and PHP so please let me know if there is any other information I can supply.

I have custom text fields where I enter product prices. I am using the Custom Content By Country plugin so that I can display region-specific prices in these fields. This plugin uses a shortcode to specify what prices should be displayed for each country. For example:

```
[CBC country="gb" show="y"]£10[/CBC][CBC country=“us” show=“y”]$15[/CBC]
```

I worked out how to use the `do_shortcode` function in my template to actually get the shortcode to work, like this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'fl_prodbuy1price', true) );?>
```

This works fine the first time I publish the post. My problem is that, once I click Publish/Update in the Wordpress UI, Wordpress truncates the displayed contents of the field - always at the first equals (=) sign:

```
[CBC country=
```

So if I go back and edit the post and update it, unless I remember to re-enter the full shortcode it publishes the post with a value of **[CBC country=** for the price.

Does this problem ring any bells for anyone? I’d appreciate any suggestions on where I should focus investigation.

Comment: it's probably incorrect handling of quotes somewhere.

Comment: @Milo is right, maybe run it through [`esc_attr()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr)

Comment: Thanks - I'll give that a go and see what I can find out.

Answer (score 0):

@Milo and @Howdy_McGee had the answer.

I found the section I needed to modify in my functions.php file:

```
case 'text':
echo '<input type="text" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" 
value="', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '" size="30" style="width:97%" />',
```

It was the value field that was getting truncated, so I passed it through esc_attr() as suggested:

```
case 'text':
echo '<input type="text" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" 
value="', esc_attr($meta ? $meta : $field['std']), '" size="30"   style="width:97%" />',
```

Problem solved.